# My webpage refreshes after the javascript runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh

I am making this quiz for my economics class. I chose to do it in java script. after my script runs the page refreshes. The page is just supposed to change the color of the input tags background. What am I doing wrong? The first block of variables collect the information, the second set the variables to lowercase. The code works fine when it is in the html file, but I want it to be an external javascript.

EDIT: I did what Simon said to do, by removing the [return false;] from my js and changed my onclick to [onclick="return checkAnswers();"], but I am still experiencing the same issue.

EDIT: I did what Duncan said and it works perfectly now, thank you!

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html />

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chapter 2</title>

        <style type="text/css">
         input{
          width:150px;
          border:none;
          border-bottom:solid 1px #C0C0C0;
          text-align:center;
         }
         h1, h3, body{
          text-align:center;
         }
         div{
          border:double 3px #C0C0C0;
          margin:5px;
          padding:10px;
          border-radius:5%;
          text-align:left;
         }
         a:link, a:visited{
          color:#0000FF;
         }
         a:hover{
          color:#CC00FF;
          font-size:1.5em;
         }
         #sect2def2{
          width:200px;
         }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript\script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Chapter 3</h1>
        <form>
            <a name="notes"></a><h3>Notes</h3>
            <div id="section1">
                <h3>Section 1</h3>
                <input type="text" id="sect1def1"></input> is another name for capitalism, an economic system based on private ownership of productive resources.
                <br />
                <input type="text" id="sect1def2"></input> is the ability of everyone to take part in the market by free choice.
                <br />
                <input type="text" id="sect1def3"></input> is a situation in which everyone has the same economic rights under the law.
                <br />
                A <input type="text" id="sect1def4"></input> is a situation in which people decide which legal agreements to enter into.
                <br />
                The <input type="text" id="sect1def5"></input> is the force that encourages people and organizations to improve their material well being from economic activities.
            </div>
            <div id="section 2">
                <h3>Section 2</h3>
                <input type="text" id="sect2def1"></input> is the money left over after the costs of producing a good or service have been subtracted from the revenue gained by selling that good or service.
                <br />
                A <input type="text" id="sect2def2"></input> is a free enterprise economic system with some government involvement.
            </div>
            <div id="section 3">
                <h3>Section 3</h3>
                <input type="text" id="sect3def1"></input> occurs when people who are not part of a marketplace interaction benefit from it or pay part of its costs.
                <br />
                <input type="text" id="sect3def2"></input> are products provided by federal, state, and local governments and consumed by the public as a group.
                <br />
                A <input type="text" id="sect3def3"></input> is a person who avoids paying for a good or service but who benefits from that good or service anyway.
                <br />
                The <input type="text" id="sect3def4"></input> consists of all the  goods and services that are necessary for the functioning of society.
                <br />
                An <input type="text" id="sect3def5"></input> is a side effect of a product that affects someone other than the producer or the buyer.
                <br />
                A <input type="text" id="sect3def6"></input> is an externality that imposes costs on people who were not involved in the original economic activity.
                <br />
                A <input type="text" id="sect3def7"></input> is an externality that creates benefits for people who were not involved in the original economic activity.
                <br />
                A <input type="text" id="sect3def8"></input> is a government payment that helps cover the cost of an economic activity that has  the potential to benefit the public as a whole.
                <br />
                The <input type="text" id="sect3def9"></input> consists of government programs designed to protect people from economic hardships.
                <br />
                <input type="text" id="sect3def10"></input> are transfers of income from one person or group to another even though the receiver does not provide anything in return.
                <br />
                A <input type="text" id="sect3def11"></input> is a transfer payment in which the government transfers income from taxpayers to recipients who do not provide anything in return.
            </div>
            <button id="notesButton" onclick="checkAnswers();">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function checkAnswers() {
    var s1d1 = document.getElementById("sect1def1").value;
    var s1d2 = document.getElementById("sect1def2").value;
    var s1d3 = document.getElementById("sect1def3").value;
    var s1d4 = document.getElementById("sect1def4").value;
    var s1d5 = document.getElementById("sect1def5").value;
    var s2d1 = document.getElementById("sect2def1").value;
    var s2d2 = document.getElementById("sect2def2").value;
    var s3d1 = document.getElementById("sect3def1").value;
    var s3d2 = document.getElementById("sect3def2").value;
    var s3d3 = document.getElementById("sect3def3").value;
    var s3d4 = document.getElementById("sect3def4").value;
    var s3d5 = document.getElementById("sect3def5").value;
    var s3d6 = document.getElementById("sect3def6").value;
    var s3d7 = document.getElementById("sect3def7").value;
    var s3d8 = document.getElementById("sect3def8").value;
    var s3d9 = document.getElementById("sect3def9").value;
    var s3d10 = document.getElementById("sect3def10").value;
    var s3d11 = document.getElementById("sect3def11").value;

    var s1d1L = s1d1.toLowerCase();
    var s1d2L = s1d2.toLowerCase();
    var s1d3L = s1d3.toLowerCase();
    var s1d4L = s1d4.toLowerCase();
    var s1d5L = s1d5.toLowerCase();
    var s2d1L = s2d1.toLowerCase();
    var s2d2L = s2d2.toLowerCase();
    var s3d1L = s3d1.toLowerCase();
    var s3d2L = s3d2.toLowerCase();
    var s3d3L = s3d3.toLowerCase();
    var s3d4L = s3d4.toLowerCase();
    var s3d5L = s3d5.toLowerCase();
    var s3d6L = s3d6.toLowerCase();
    var s3d7L = s3d7.toLowerCase();
    var s3d8L = s3d8.toLowerCase();
    var s3d9L = s3d9.toLowerCase();
    var s3d10L = s3d10.toLowerCase();
    var s3d11L = s3d11.toLowerCase();

    if (s1d1L=="free enterprise system"){
        document.getElementById("sect1def1").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect1def1").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (s1d2L=="open opportunity"){
        document.getElementById("sect1def2").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect1def2").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (s1d3L=="legal equality"){
        document.getElementById("sect1def3").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect1def3").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (s1d4L=="free contract"){
        document.getElementById("sect1def4").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect1def4").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (s1d5L=="profit motive"){
        document.getElementById("sect1def5").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect1def5").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (s2d1L=="profit"){
        document.getElementById("sect2def1").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect2def1").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (s2d2L=="modified free enterprise economy"){
        document.getElementById("sect2def2").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect2def2").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (s3d1L=="market failure"){
        document.getElementById("sect3def1").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect3def1").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (s3d2L=="public goods"){
        document.getElementById("sect3def2").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect3def2").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (s3d3L=="free rider"){
        document.getElementById("sect3def3").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect3def3").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (s3d4L=="infrastructure"){
        document.getElementById("sect3def4").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect3def4").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (s3d5L=="externality"){
                    document.getElementById("sect3def5").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect3def5").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (s3d6L=="negative externality"){
        document.getElementById("sect3def6").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect3def6").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (s3d7L=="positive externality"){
        document.getElementById("sect3def7").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect3def7").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (s3d8L=="subsidy"){
        document.getElementById("sect3def8").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect3def8").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (s3d9L=="safety net"){
        document.getElementById("sect3def9").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect3def9").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (s3d10L=="transfer payments"){
        document.getElementById("sect3def10").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect3def10").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    if (s3d11L=="public transfer payment"){
        document.getElementById("sect3def11").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sect3def11").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: There are all sorts of ways that you could cut down the amount of code you've got tremendously. Those separate variables should all be part of an array initialized with a loop. Those tests can all be reduced to a map lookup. Your immediate problem is probably in the answer from @Simon.

Comment: I am a beginner in javascript and I know there is a simpler way to do this but I am limited with my knowledge.

Comment: Well don't feel bad. Any time you find yourself typing almost exactly the same line of code over and over again, then there's something you probably should explore to avoid that :)

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return false in your onclick handler (you're only doing so in your function). Something like this might be fine:

```
<button id="notesButton" onclick="return checkAnswers();">Submit</button>
```

EDIT: It is even better to bind the function to the form's onsubmit, in case of somebody submits the form with the keyboard without the use of your button.

Comment: I removed the "return false;" and added the "onclick="return checkAnswers();"" but I still have the same issue.

Comment: You need both. Without the return false in the method. The method doesn't return anything. With the "return checkAnswers()" in the on click handler it passes the returned value from the method to the click event of the button. by returning false to the click event handler. It stops it from triggering the default function.